# ruby language syntax(how platform_info variable is used

Tags: ruby, syntax

```
 class EncodeDemoTest < Test                      #inheritance in ruby  
      def setup(platform_info, logdir)
        @telnet_ip                  = platform_info["telnet_ip"]
        @telnet_login               = platform_info["telnet_login"]
        @telnet_password            = nil
        @filesys_path               = platform_info["filesys_path"]
        @host_files_path            = platform_info["host_files_path"]
        @host_machine_ip            = platform_info["host_machine_ip"]
        @linuxserver_ip             = platform_info["linuxserver_ip"]
        @target_prompt              = platform_info["target_prompt"]
        @demo_execuable_path        = platform_info["demo_execuable_path"]
        @mts4ea_machine_ip          = platform_info["mts4ea_machine_ip"]
        @mts4ea_files_path          = platform_info["mts4ea_files_path"]
        @ffmpeg_machine_ip          = platform_info["ffmpeg_machine_ip"]
        @ffmpeg_service_machine_ip  = platform_info["ffmpeg_service_machine_ip"]          
        @ffmpeg_files_path          = platform_info["ffmpeg_files_path"]
        @ffmpeg_login               = platform_info["ffmpeg_login"]
        @ffmpeg_password            = platform_info["ffmpeg_password"]
        @ffmpeg_prompt              = platform_info["ffmpeg_prompt"]
        @platform_info              = platform_info
```

could anyone tell me how argument passed in setup method .means what does that syntax means `platform_info["telnet_ip"]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `platform_info` is intended to be a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html).

`setup` would be called with something like `setup({'telnet_ip' => 'value'}, 'logdir_value')` and `platform_info["telnet_ip"]` would then return the value from `platform_info` for the key `"telnet_ip"`.

**Update**

Given the code:

```
@board = Target::TelnetClient.new "192.168.247.68", "root", 
  @telnet_password, logdir + "/log.txt"
app = Target::EncodeDemoApp.new() app.setup(@board, @demo_execuable_path)
```

it looks like `@board` is not a `Hash` but is a `Target::TelnetClient` which must have a `[]` method that makes it behave like a `Hash`.

If you want to find out what class something is you can use the `class` method e.g. you can put in your program:

```
puts "@board is a #{@board.class}"
puts "@demo_executable_path is a #{@demo_executable_path.class}"
```

For `@board`, to see what values it contains (telnet_ip, telnet_login etc) you could try:

```
puts @board.keys.inspect
```

Finally, to see the methods that an object provides you can use `public_methods` e.g.

```
puts @board.public_methods.inspect
```

Comment: thanks mikej,but could u plz expain it more like how i confirm platform_info  is hash and is there any other way to call setup function other than what u wrote plzzz i m waiting gor ur  respone

Comment: thanks mikej,but could u plz expain it more like how i confirm platform_info is hash and is there any other way to call setup function other than what u wrote plzzz i m waiting gor ur respone

Comment: nd i adding one  line 
  @board = Target::TelnetClient.new "192.168.247.68", "root", @telnet_password, logdir + "/log.txt"
          setup(@board,@demoexecuatable path)
now cud  u plz explain more

Comment: Please can you add some more details about what else you would like to know. I'm not sure what to add. Why would you like to call the function in a different way? What is that extra line for that you want to add?

Comment: i understood what u said platform_info is definately HASH but setup function is called like that

 app = Target::EncodeDemoApp.new()
        app.setup(@board, @demo_execuable_path)
one line before this is 
@board = Target::TelnetClient.new "192.168.247.68", "root", @telnet_password, logdir + "/log.txt"
one thing that i want to know is what value is there inside instance variable @board and how to determine @board value i tried with puts #{@board} but nt wrking and one more thins islogdir is also hesh ?? excuse if there is sumthing wrong because i new to ruby

Comment: mikej i tried with keys method but its not working 
cud u plzzz tell someelse methods???

Comment: Can you do `puts @board.class` and let me know what that prints.

Comment: Also, what is the output from `puts @board.public_methods.inspect`?

Comment: yaa @board.public_methods.inspect and @board.class are working fine like
@board.class gives me TelnetClient class name 
but when i tried @board.keys.inspect i have trouble like  undefined method `keys'

Comment: Can you find the code for the `TelnetClient` class? I don't think that is a standard part of Ruby so it is either specific to your project or a third party library.

Comment: mikej i m facing a problem like as i asked before 

@board = Target::TelnetClient.new "192.168.247.68", "root",  
  @telnet_password, logdir + "/log.txt" 
is @board is a hash or what ??
and u replied like it is a hash and to me it seems a hash but when i used standard ruby operator like @board.kind_of? Hash i got false as an output
so this measns it's not hash 
nd this code for telnetclient

Comment: module Target
  class TelnetClient < Client
    def initialize(ip, login, password, log_path = nil)
      super(log_path)

      connect(ip, login, password)
    end

    def connect(ip, login, password)
      @target = Net::Telnet::new( "Host" => ip)

      if(password == nil)
        @target.login(login.to_s, nil){ |c| print c}
      else
        @target.login(login.to_s, password){ |c| print c }
      end

      super()
    end
  end
end

Comment: From the code you've posted it is not a `Hash`. `TelnetClient < Client` says that `TelnetClient` extends `Client` so some of the methods like the ability to say `platform_info["telnet_ip"]` must come from the `Client` class but there is no `keys` method.

Comment: hii mikej
i wouls like to know is there any way to map a mdb(database) file to hash .

Comment: Mapping an mdb to a hash should be posted as a new question.